# Aritmetic Operations on Conditional type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference, typescript-conditional-types

Im tryng to define a generic type that takes a number and  its defined as true if the number provided is divisible by 4.
Is that possible ?
The code Im tryng is this:

```js
type isDivisibleBy4<T extends number> = T extends number ? (T%4 extends 0 ?true:never) :never
```

So for starters I need to Know if aritmetic operation are possible involving types.
And then how do i make that happen?

Comment: Naive, using tuples: https://tsplay.dev/NllxlN Better, using divisibility rules: https://tsplay.dev/wR097m

Comment: You can't do math with types. Well, [actually you can](https://itnext.io/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f) but it's really not a great idea. The approach is use tuples that have lengths to represent integers and lots and lots of recursive types. It's also _really_ complicated.

Comment: @vr. Not sure that actually works `IsDivisibleBy4<1001>` is `true` https://tsplay.dev/NVYglw

Comment: Wow, how do i learn to do that?
Im far from understanding your code. is there anything i can read to understand better?

Comment: @AlexWayne Oh, well that seems to be caused by numbers with leading zeroes being parsed as `number`. It can be easily fixed by checking if `A` is `"0"` beforehand: https://tsplay.dev/w22E1w

Comment: My approach was created specifically to check if a number is divisible by 4. If you need more versatile arithmetic, you could check out the article linked by Alex, but there's also tons of projects out there that revolve around doing type level computations.

Comment: The relevant feature request is [ms/TS#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382); you can abuse template literal types ([here's my attempt](https://tsplay.dev/mA8v1N)) or tuple types to get similar behavior, but neither of those are really meant for that purpose.  Does that fully address the question?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I belive so Ill work up to that aproach i think this is the way thanks for Your time make  the answere so ill check it