# How to create a type that only accepts numbers multiple of 4?

Tags: typescript

`type MultipleOfFour = ???`

`const someValue: MultipleOfFour = 9` -> ❌ Error because 9 is not multiple of 4

`const someValue: MultipleOfFour = 8` -> ✅

Comment: You could adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76907391/157247). Note the limitations.

Comment: Strongly related: [Aritmetic Operations on Conditional type definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75882606).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific `MultipleOfFour` type in TypeScript that works this way.  Conceptually it would be an infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like

```
// not valid TS, don't do this
type MultipleOfFour = ⋯ | -12 | -8 | -4 | 0 | 4 | 8 | 12 | 16 | 20 | 24 | ⋯
```

But TypeScript only supports unions of up to about a 100,000 elements, and infinity is decidedly larger than that.

And since TypeScript does not currently support performing mathematical operations on numeric literal types (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382)) or the ability to use regular expressions to validate literal types (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160)), there's no specific type that says "check for divisibility by four".

---

Instead the closest you can get is to write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `MultipleOfFour<T>` that acts like a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on a type parameter `T`, such  `T extends MultipleOfFour<T>` if and only if `T` is a numeric literal representing a multiple of four.

Here's one possible approach, using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to convert numeric literal types into string literal types and to parse and inspect these string literals:

```
type LastTwo =
    `${0 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8}${0 | 4 | 8}`
    | `${1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9}${2 | 6}`;
// type LastTwo = '00' | '04' | '08' | '12' | ⋯ | '84' | '88' | '92' | '96'

type MultipleOfFour<T extends number> =
    T extends -8 | -4 | 0 | 4 | 8 ? T :
    `${T}` extends `${string}${"e" | "."}${string} ` ? 0 :
    `${T}` extends `${string}${LastTwo}` ? T :
    0;
```

So `LastTwo` is the union of 25 strings corresponding to the last two characters of the string representation of a numeric literal if it's divisible by four.  And then `MultipleOfFour<T>` checks that the string representation of the number is either a (positive or negative) one digit number divisible by four, or a longer string whose last two characters are in `LastTwo`, and which do not contain either the `"e"` or `"."` characters.  The `"e"` and `"."` characters indicate that the numeric literal is either not an integer or is so huge that it cannot accurately be represented.  I decide here that if a number is that huge then it is not an acceptable multiple of four, although it is arguable that someone might want to tweak that behavior.

Anyway if it's acceptable, then `MultipleOfFour<T>` evaluates to `T`.  Otherwise it evaluates to `0`.  In order to use it, it would be annoying to force you to write

```
const n8: MultipleOfFour<8> = 8;
```

and specify the type argument explicitly.  Instead we'd like to have the compiler *infer* the type argument.  This requires a generic utility function, since there's no facility to infer type arguments in generic *types*.  So it looks like this:

```
const multipleOfFour = <T extends number>(
    t: MultipleOfFour<T>) => t;
```

And then you use it like

```
const n8 = multipleOfFour(8);
```

which isn't the same as

```
// can't do this
const n8: MultipleOfFour = 8;
```

but is a similar amount of work for you.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const n8 = multipleOfFour(8); // okay
const n9 = multipleOfFour(9); // error
const n10 = multipleOfFour(10); // error
const n12 = multipleOfFour(12); // okay
const n100 = multipleOfFour(100); // okay
const n365 = multipleOfFour(365); // error
const n368 = multipleOfFour(368); // okay
const n8675309 = multipleOfFour(8675309); // error
const n8675308 = multipleOfFour(8675308); // okay

const nNeg500 = multipleOfFour(-500); // okay
const nNeg503 = multipleOfFour(-503); // okay
const nHalf = multipleOfFour(0.5); // error
const nDecillion = multipleOfFour(1e33); // error (too big) ‍♂️
const nBillionth = multipleOfFour(1e-9); // error 
const nInf = multipleOfFour(Infinity); // error ‍♂️
```

Looks good, I think.

---

Remember that the compiler doesn't do type level math, so even simple things like

```
const nCompilerDoesNotDoTypeLevelMath = multipleOfFour(2 + 2); // error
```

will fail.  We know that `2 + 2` is `4` but the compiler doesn't try to evaluate that.  It just knows that `2 + 2` is `number`.  And `number` isn't specific enough and is therefore rejected.

Additionally the compiler does not "understand" that `T extends MultipleOfFour<T>` implies anything about the divisibility of `T` by `4`:

```
function hmm<T extends number>(t: MultipleOfFour<T>) {
    const zero: 0 = t / 4; // error!
}
```

So the only possible usefulness of `MultipleOfFour<T>` would be to validate numeric literals written directly inside TypeScript source code.  Anything else: numbers that are only known at runtime (say from user input or API response); numbers that come from external JavaScript source code; numbers that are calculated from other numbers... these cannot be analyzed.  If your use case isn't "catch errors made by TypeScript developers writing numeric literals", then what you want is essentially impossible, and while it's interesting that one can cobble together a somewhat functional `MultipleOfFour<T>` from parts not meant for that purpose, it's beside the point.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AFQO4HsoF4BQV9QAGAJAN4AMUAPlAEzVQAsDAbAwBwC+ZlNzNXQngI0SpAIwMAzAwCsDAOwMAnN1L0aLToQDcOHKEhQAsgFcANsACWYcxADyAMwBi6UwCcAPMigQAHsAQAHYAJghQQaYAtgBGEO4AfNjC+D7+gaHhALTsDFn8ULxMHFAA-FA+AFwpRGTI2r4BwWG1pEjuVkEA5moARBC9DL0AdL1q7Z09RGWFUNUErfWEjRktYhPdavBIaOgN5VU15PoAxuhBSFBRFta2Di5u7thQ3ivN4ZGx8QkAFDXAlRMNxsdicrg83gSAEpsElgHocGcLsAIrksFdgXcwY8fuwoTooAB6QlQdAAazgIER50uQWUz2ulhB93B7h+ynxRJJ8Xc6Hc1OREXElHRjNuoIeHh+ws5xN87l5-KRtPE9FFmIlrOltFlJPJlIFKvIIoxTKxkrZwvIutJFKpypRQSkLHk6rNmpxztkNp5fMNjudaNN4pZnpYeIJcv19ppjvYLAUsik5HpbpD2Kl8cTyY5ke5Cr9DtRCaT5CDYuZGbZWdLEa5toN-oiADkIF1ZMaGRrQ1Ksh3rXmGzHBUFW+3yDI05WLT8+xObdGm0EABJwcyOLvunts8jDb2D31K2MRAAiEBOVnM5is5036Zn4ggUikPoLTx+wHQmBiVi6MMAfBuAOy7gA8G4AP-uALAEgBCZIA8H9LgAQpe17nMAAAWd7Tlqj5ZLm9aHlAS4AJJBBuU7mlqRGOJ0VigK+ipQEBYFQbBS4AMLoFEYCXvEJ7oBACDNugwA8cg4AQDAEAAG4QOYxhwKh6FkTi9AANR0LRfIADRQAAVqYtLRHE7haUEglMPoOCOKYQQnNYt4oVEUSvOk7wRAZ3wfoCZhblWkIwqQNRFgAXvE6CAiaKIkowB5vgAhDgnBAA)